# Expressão regular para links href e www/https/http

Tags: php, cakephp, regex

Bom dia, tenho 2 expressões regulares, onde uma serve para pegar a URL de qualquer `href`, e outra que preciso arrumar que seria apenas para pegar as URL's que não estão dentro de um `href`, ou seja, só as URL's digitadas com começo `www`, `https://` e `http://`. Com a segunda expressão não posso pegar as urls que estão dentro do href.

1°Expressão para pegar os href

```
preg_replace('/href="(?!http:\/\/)([^"]+)"/e', '$this->href("$1", "$id", "$posi_email")', $texto);
```

2°Expressão que não devia pegar as urls dentro de uma href.

```
preg_replace('/(www.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[^ ]+?([^,])+)/e', '$this->url("$1", "$id", "$posi_email")', $texto);
```

Comment: fiquei na dúvida na sua segunda expressão com o que você precisa casar o texto. Seria qualquer link da página?

Comment: Muito cuidado com esse `preg_replace` com modificador `e`. Já foi depreciado!

Answer (score 1):

**Não** usem expressão regular (RegEx) para fazer parsing de HTML. RegEx **não** é a ferramenta mais apropriada para fazer isso.

Existem diversos **frameworks** para fazer isso em praticamente qualquer linguagem. Em PHP dá para fazer nativamente com [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) ou com o [XML Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). Em Phyton tem o [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Em Java tem o [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/). E assim por diante.

Não tem como deixar de linkar para uma das perguntas mais famosas do Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags